# How do you export Servers in Eclipse/SpringToolSuite?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-tool-suite, tomcat9

Is there a way to export both Server launch configurations and the actual Servers (e.g. as seen in the 'Servers' view)?

I have four Tomcat Servers configured in Eclipse/STS, corresponding to four Server launch configurations.   I want to export both of these sets so I can import into another workspace.

The Eclipse Export wizard has an 'Export Launch Configurations' but there is no apparent option to export the actual Servers and their associated settings (server name, ports, modules, etc).

Given the maturity of Eclipse assume it is there and I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a direct export present. But there seems to be another way of doing it. You can go the properties of the server you want you export. You will find 'Configuration path' over there. You can click on browser and copy the desired configurations.[image]

All the configurations for that particular server are stored in that location. Sometimes this shows up in your package explorer as well if config is present inside workspace.

[image]

You may right click on the servers folder(inside pakage explorer) and then select show in>System explorer.
You can copy the server config and replace them on the other machine's workspace.

Similarly if you really want to copy servers, in server properties if you scroll down, you'll find 'server path' and 'deploy path'. You can navigate to that path and replace them on your new machine.

[image]